# How to insert text at a bookmark with keeping style in Microsoft Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have set certain bookmarks in my word document and I want to insert text from a txt file. Below is my code:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(myTextMark).Range.InsertFile FileName:=locations, ConfirmConversions:=False
```

I find the inserted text is the default setting of my word.

Is it possible to set the inserted text with font name, size, color, and set the paragraph indent?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for asking Olle. I know 
wdApp.Selection.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
should work with crusor selection. However, I insert the text with a bookmark. Is it possible to pick up inserted text as selection or something like
Bookmarks(myTextMark).Font.Name = "Times New Roman"?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell because you do not include enough code around the `InsertFile` sample, but I would guess your code *replaces* the bookmark in the document. That makes it hard to adress just where the inserted text is placed. The trick here is to figure out what part of the document to change the font for. This can be done in a number of ways.

I would suggest the following, where you first set the cursor to *after* the bookmark, then insert the text. That way, the bookmark is still there after you have inserted the text, and you can use it with the current position to adress just the inserted text:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertAndUpdateText()
    Const myTextMark = 1
    Const locations = "C:\test.txt"

    '***** Select bookmark
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(myTextMark).Range.Select
    '***** Set the cursor to the end of the bookmark range
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    '***** Insert text
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:=locations, ConfirmConversions:=False

    '***** Create new Range object
    Dim oRng As Range

    '***** Set oRng to text between the end of the bookmark and the start of the current position
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(myTextMark).Range.End, Selection.Range.Start)

    '***** Do whatever with the new range
    oRng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
    oRng.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"

    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

BTW, regarding your comment, the font for the bookmark can also be changed by using the same range object you use for inserting the text (ie `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(myTextMark).Range.Font = "Times New Roman"`), but that would only change the font for the bookmark, not the newly inserted text.

Comment: @hadesmajesty please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.